# redis : delete keys not starting with prefix

Tags: redis

Is there any option in redis(config) or dynomite(config), like only specified list of key-prefix are allowed?

example

`list-of-key-prefix : ["abc","xyz"]`

then only keys having prefix from given list will be allowed to store and all other will be not stored?

example

```
keys_allowed : ["abc_cow", "abcdog", "xyzcat", "xyzrat"]

keys_not_allowed : ["animal-cat","doganimal"]
```

Comment: There's no such config. You need to do that in the application code.

Answer (score -1):

you can Implement a simple python script for this task, example snippet below:

```
prefix_list=['abc', 'xyz']
keys=["abc_cow", "abcdog", "xyzcat", "xyzrat", "animal-cat","doganimal"]
for key in keys:
    if key.startswith(perfix_list[0]) or key.startswith(perfix_list[1]):
        #store key refer: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py
    else:
        print "Key not staisfy prefix List"
```